# How to install libgpuarray Windows

Tags: windows, build, windows-10, deep-learning

I'm trying to install libgpuarray on a windows 10 device. The instructions on their website [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html) are a little confusing as I'm new to windows builds and development. Could someone please provide instructions with explanation (assume I know little) for installing this software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just successfully built the libgpuarray...

Here's a helpful page: [Add windows install instructions #264](https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray/issues/264)

---

So first, you need to have a compiler. 
I'm using Visual Studio 2015, MinGW/MSYS should also work in this project, but I'm not familiar with those compilers.

Second, you need to install `cmake` before your build, just go to their [official site](https://cmake.org/) and download it.
I did not try other options, but if you're using python, libgpuarray will also require `mako` to be installed.

Then, carefully follow the steps in the link above(copied here with some notes).

> Clone the library from GitHub.
>
> Create build folder, open CMake gui **(I suggest to run a command like this before using gui:** `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"`**, I always got errors using gui to create config)**
>
> Change CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to libgpuarray/lib **(just use the folder you want to install, it defaults to "C:\Program Files\libgpuarray")**. Perhaps this should be default on windows. 
>  **(I also set** `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` **)**
>
> Configure and generate. **(should be no error here)**
>
> Open the .sln file with Visual Studio
>
> Build the INSTALL package (needs PR #263)
>
> Manually move the dll's to somewhere in the PATH. Perhaps we should automate this on windows.

If you don't need to setup for python, you can stop now.

---

> Build the Cython extension (in the libgpuarray root) with: `python setup.py build_ext --compiler=msvc` 
> **(before this setup command, you may need to run** `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64` **)**
>
> Install the package with `python setup.py install`

---

Hope this can help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm even more newbie to these "building things"... could you help me with these questions? 1 - Are `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` environment vars on windows? 2 - How to "configure and generate"? 3 - By build the install package, is it simply building a solution on visual studio like a regular vs project? 4 - When you say libgpuarray root, is it simply `libgpuarray` or `libgpuarray\lib`? (other install instructions seem to use the `lib` folder)

Comment: By "manually move the dll's to somewhere in the PATH", it means: take the "dll" **AND the "lib" files** that were generated in `<libgpu-cloned-root>\lib\ReleaseOrDebug` and move them to just `<libgpu-cloned-root>\lib`.

Comment: 1 - both `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` are used as environment vars on Windows here, I use `set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`. 2 - use `cmake ..` if you are in a subfolder like this guide..( I actually forgot how to do it and have to do it again to confirm..) 3 - yes. 4 - `libgpuarray\lib`. 5 - move it somewhere or leave it here, both ok, just add the folder to PATH so programs can find it.